# sort a list of different type of objects

Tags: java

I have a list of objects which contains different types of objects but a single property is common among all.
list contains objects of Field class, Button Class, Page class etc but one property is common among all i.e. "sequence_no" &
I want to sort this list on the basis of "sequence_no".

Comment: Have all this objects a common Super class?

Comment: @David :There is no inheritance at all.

Comment: Is the property name `sequence_no` for all the classes?

Comment: @  TDG: yes this is common in all the classes..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd suggest creating an interface, something like "`Sequenceable`" with a method `getSequenceNo()`.

```
public interface Sequenceable {
    int getSequenceNo();
}
```

Your `Field`, `Button`, `Page` classes should implement this interface and the `getSequenceNo()` method will return your `sequence_no`.

Then you can implement your own `Comparator` and sort using this comparator.

For example, your comparator will look like:

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<Sequenceable> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Sequenceable o1, Sequenceable o2) {
        return o2.getSequenceNo() - o1.getSequenceNo();
    }
}
```

Then you can sort with:

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());
```

Comment: If he can change the declaration of all the classes i think this is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

If there are a few classes you want to sort (Field,Button,Page...) you could do a Class that inherits from `Comparator<Object>`  and use the `java.lang.Object.getClass()` and `casting` in an switch clasusule.

Something like:

```
public class MyComparator implements Comparator<Object>{
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            int o1prop,o2prop;
            switch (o1.getClass().toString()) {
            case "java.Button":
                ((Button)o1prop).getSequence_no();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            switch (o2.getClass().toString()) {
            case "java.Field":
                ((Field)o1prop).getSequence_no();
                break;

            default:
                break;
            }

            return o1prop-o2prop;
        }
```

And after that use:

```
Collections.sort(list, new MyComparator());
```

Answer (score 0):

All your objects should be exetended or inheritance by some and same super class, then the compiler will not ask you to explicitly change those objects.

Answer (score 0):

The best and clean way is to have your class  implementing an interface or extending a common base class .

Other way can be (which i don't prefer becpz of performance, readability and cleanliness), create a custom comparator that uses reflection which checks the
 type and then compare the property